# Get Thumbnail from Video file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get thumbnail from video file and my code run successfully but thumbnail is not saved here is my code..

```
 protected void Convert(string fileIn, string fileOut, string thumbOut)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process ffmpeg;

            string video;
            string thumb;

            video = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadVedio/YouTube.FLV");
            thumb = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadImage/frame.jpg");

            ffmpeg = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i " + video + " -ss 00:00:07 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg " + thumb;
            ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/EXE/ffmpeg.exe");
            ffmpeg.Start();
            ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
            ffmpeg.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code are running in IIS, make sure you have write right to the proper folder

Comment: how to check who will run ffmpeg.exe Sir? If we run it at IIS server?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check :

1. Is the directory contain space(s)? If so, please add :

   video = "\"" + video + "\"";
   thumb = "\"" + thumb  + "\"";
2. Is ffmpeg.exe path is correct? If you want to set up environment variable for ffmpeg, go [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) so you do not need locate where ffmpeg.exe path to run ffmpeg.
3. i.e. your argument : -ss 00:00:07. Is the video length longer than 7 second?
4. Copy ffmpeg.exe to drive C (if you do not set path for ffmpeg) and Try to run directly at cmd, and post here what is the output if any error(s) occured? i.e:

   c:\ffmpeg.exe  -i "c:\video.mp4" -ss 00:00:07 -vframes 1 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg "c:\result.jpg"